# CSS: Centering two elements within a div with custom heights

Tags: css, alignment

I have a list of page titles that I want to display with a font awesome symbol next to them.

```
<div>
    <ul class="form-navigation">
        <li ng-repeat="..."
            ng-click="...">
            <div>
                <a href="">{{QuestionGroup.Title}}</a>
                <span class="pull-right fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color: red;"></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want the text to be centered vertically and the FA symbol to be centered horizontally and vertically. I've tried a range of different things with putting them in different divs and applying various styles but I can't get anything to work.

The symbol is the biggest issue, because I could centre it by adding padding at the top/bottom but because my page titles have random lengths they might take up more than 1 row causing the div to be a different size.

Comment: Line-height should do the trick. Can you make a demo?

Answer (score 0):

Use table to align them properly

```
<div>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="">This is lol</a>
         <td>
         <td>
             <span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color: red;"></span>
         <td>
     </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Just...No. CSS tables maybe but not tables for layout.